# Swift 3, Alamofire 4, JSON Dictionary: Only displaying last JSON entry

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, alamofire

For some reason, my code is only displaying the last entry in the JSON file... No errors, just not properly displaying all the sets in the `UICollectionView`.

```
class vcWatch: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var images:[String] = [] // @IBOutlet weak var imageCell: UIImageView!
var lableTitles:[String] = [] // @IBOutlet weak var labelCell: UILabel!
let pageURL = "http://alifetouched.com/lib/videos.json.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadImages()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let myCell:cvCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! cvCell

    myCell.labelCell.text = self.lableTitles[indexPath.row]

    let imageString = self.images[indexPath.row]
    let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageString)
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl! as URL)

    if(imageData != nil){
        myCell.imageCell.image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
    }

    return myCell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    print("User Tapped: \(indexPath.row)")
}

func loadImages() {
    myActivityIndicator.isHidden = false
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    Alamofire.request(pageURL)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { (response) in

            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                print("Error with response: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            guard let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary <String,AnyObject> else {
                print("Error with dictionary: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            guard let dictData = dict["VideoJSON"] as? [Dictionary <String,AnyObject>] else {
                print("Error with dictionary data: \(response.result.error)")
                return
            }

            for videos in dictData {
                self.myActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                self.images = [videos["icon_url"] as! String]
                self.lableTitles = [videos["title"] as! String]
                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
            return
    }
}
}
```

I know I am just not thinking straight...Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is inside your for loop, inside that you need to append the object in array instead of that you are initializing the Array with single object, also you need to reload the `collectionView` outside the for loop after all the object added in array not inside the loop. Also you need to put `myActivityIndicator` before the for loop or after the loop not inside the loop because it will execute same code multiple times and there no need of that.

```
self.myActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
for videos in dictData {

    self.images.append(videos["icon_url"] as! String)
    self.lableTitles.append([videos["title"] as! String)
}
self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
```

**Note:** One suggestion instead of maintaining two different arrays of type `[String]` you need to main Single array of type `[[String: Any]]` and use that array in your collectionView method like `myCell.labelCell.text = self.dicArr[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String`.

Comment: WOW! Fast and accurate...just ran it with the update and it is working great.  Thank you so much for your time - Perfect Answer.  I clicked the rating but I believe I am under 15 to score you.  Please score Nirav D - His solution is spot on.

Comment: @user3144951 Welcome mate :) Also check the edited answer :)

Comment: I'll try the self.dicarr when I get back home tonight. Unfortunately, I haven't set up a dictionary properly before.. but I am up for a challenge. I need to set that up in the cellforitemat function or in the load function? Sorry, I really want to understand this so I can use this understanding in the future..and pay it forward. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm - Tried what I believed to be what you were talking about, but honestly I have no idea where to add what... Any further assistance with that would be helpful - thank you.

Comment: Actually, to get you credit Nirav, I'll add another question for the resolution.,

Comment: @Dortoh You want me to edit the answer with that array of dictionary that i have suggested you or something else.

Answer (score 0):

first create array to get the alamofire response. than add the response name **"VideoJSON"** array into your array 
than give count of your array in numberofiteminsection 
and than after get the url from that array which you added earlier

your this method only get the last entry

```
for videos in dictData {
            self.myActivityIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            self.images = [videos["icon_url"] as! String]
            self.lableTitles = [videos["title"] as! String]
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
```